# Intent.getInt() doesn't work on ICS, but works on JB

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I use this code to send parameters when I start a new Activity:

```
Intent inputForm = new Intent(getActivity(), InputForm.class);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("item", Integer.parseInt(mItem.id)); //Your id
inputForm.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(inputForm);
```

And I use this code for reading the parameters in the inputForm Activity:

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        int value = b.getInt("item");
        ID = value;
    }

Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "MIJN ID:" + Integer.toString(ID), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When I run this code on my Samsung Tab 10.1 GT-P7510 ID (and my Samsung Tab 2 10.1 3G GT-P5100) is alsways 0, when I run the same code on my Galaxy S3 with JB the code just works fine. When I use this code I get this error:

```
Intent inputForm = new Intent(getActivity(), InputForm.class);
inputForm.putExtra("item", mItem.id);
startActivityForResult(inputForm, 0);

//Read Settings in new Activity

String message;

message = getIntent().getExtras().getString("item"); //<---Nullpointerexception
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

> E/AndroidRuntime(2274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity ComponentInfo{com.obat.tabtasks/com.obat.tabtasks.InputForm}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Thanks in advance,

ObAt

Comment: are you sure mItem.id is not zero on the Samsung Tab 10.1 GT-P7510 ?

Comment: Yes, I start the new Activity from a Master/Detail Flow. I have 3 Fragments and on each Fragment mItem.id is diffirent. mItem.id has to be 1 when I launch the second Fragment, and 2 when I launch the thirth Fragment.

Comment: mItem.id is a String? could you print out its value before put it in bundle?

Comment: and in inputForm Activity b is not  null?

Comment: I tested it and b is null, I don't why because on my SGS3 b is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Intent inputForm = new Intent(getActivity(), InputForm.class);
inputFrom.putExtra("item",Integer.parseInt(mItem.id));
startActivity(inputForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you split the line in

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   String message = bundle.getString("passed");
```

and check again where the NPE is?

Comment: What is the Android version tablet and from where are you creating the Intent? (the getActivity() call suggests is not within another activity)

Comment: 4.0.4 and this is my Activity public class TaskDetailFragment extends Fragment

Comment: I also tried with a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 3G (GT-P5100) with stock Android 4.0.4

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944503/android-getintent-getextras-returns-null, perhaps its the same problem than you (he was using tabs)

Comment: I tried everything on the link but I can't fix it. I also tried to use this code but getArguments is not defined in my class:    if (getArguments().containsKey("myItem")) {
     ID = MyTasks.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }

Comment: Fixed, I just use a static integer from another class

Comment: You mean static properties to pass variables between Activities?