# Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, asynchronous

I pass a bundle through an intent and start an activity, but it is not executing. The exception in the log is

```
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.y.httpcommunicationhelper2/com.x.y..httpcommunicationhelper2.logout}: java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

Could you point out the error. Could you help out ?The code is:

```
//Intent part 
if (result != null) {
    Intent tokenIntent = new Intent(mContext, tokenActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("responsedata", result.substring(result.indexOf("=") + 1, result.length()));

    tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(tokenIntent);


    //logout class

    public class logout extends Activity {

        TextView logouttext;
        Bundle bundle2;
        Context mContext;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

            mContext = this;
            logouttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlogout);
            bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();

            Log.i("logout - ats token", bundle2.getString("responsedata"));

            URLconnector ss = new URLconnector();
            ss.execute("url");

        }


        private class URLconnector extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {
                String response = "";
                for (String url: urls) {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    try {

                        List < NameValuePair > postParameters = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();

                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appID", "hjbhjbh"));
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("atsToken", bundle2.getString("responsedata")));

                        Log.i("logout - ats token", bundle2.getString("responsedata"));


                        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            postParameters);

                        httppost.setEntity(formEntity);


                        HttpResponse logoutresp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        Log.i("Logout response ", logoutresp.toString());
```

The error log is :

```
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.y.httpcommunicationhelper2/com.x.y..httpcommunicationhelper2.logout}: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at com.x.y.httpcommunicationhelper2.logout.onCreate(logout.java:52)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-25 21:11:44.514: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: can you show how you invoke your logout activity? is it possible your `bundle2` is empty, if i'm right have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944503/android-getintent-getextras-returns-null this might be related

Comment: @Ahmad     Log.i("logout - ats token" ,bundle2.getString("responsedata"));

Comment: @user902383 if (result != null) {
    Intent tokenIntent = new Intent(mContext, tokenActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("responsedata", result.substring(result.indexOf("=") + 1, result.length()));

    tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(tokenIntent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lines:

```
bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();

Log.i("logout - ats token", bundle2.getString("responsedata"));
```

to

```
bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle2  != null) {
       Log.i("logout - ats token", bundle2.getString("responsedata"));
}
```

You will also need to change the code of `URLconnector` accordingly.

Comment: the error is gone now. What change should be made in the URLconnector ? Nothing from logout is being logged actually now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Similar thing, check if `bundle2` is not null as it may be null.

Comment: Nothing from logout is being logged actually now , no network response too

Comment: You execute your `AsyncTask` with the param `url` in `ss.execute("url");`. Did you want to pass a URL in here? You're passing a hardcoded string...

Comment: yes i want to pass a url, i have not mentioned the exact url because of certain reasons

Comment: Of course, sorry. Not sure but that may be a separate question. Maybe you can close that one and ask another one with the new code?

Comment: Great to hear. Good luck!